# Oracle DB connector in Play Framework 2.5

Tags: oracle11g, ebean, playframework-2.5

I have a simple Java Play! Framework 2.5 project. I want to connect it to an Oracle DB 11g in AWS RDS. I've put the Oracle DB connector in the `/lib` directory (which is "ojdbc6.jar", found [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/apps-tech/jdbc-112010-090769.html)). I've also configured Ebean and the Evolutions plugin.

When I do `activator run` and load "localhost:9000" on my browser, this message appears at the console:

```
[info] application - Creating Pool for datasource 'default'
[warn] c.z.h.u.DriverDataSource - Registered driver with driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver was not found, trying direct instantiation.
[info] application - Creating Pool for datasource 'default'
[warn] c.z.h.u.DriverDataSource - Registered driver with driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver was not found, trying direct instantiation.
```

This is followed by the evolutions page, after accepting the evolutions there is an error. This is the stack trace:

```
[error] application - 

! @701gfbl3i - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [default]]
    at play.api.Configuration$.configError(Configuration.scala:154)
    at play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:806)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi$$anonfun$connect$1.apply(DefaultDBApi.scala:48)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi$$anonfun$connect$1.apply(DefaultDBApi.scala:42)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi.connect(DefaultDBApi.scala:42)
    at play.api.db.DBApiProvider.get$lzycompute(DBModule.scala:72)
    at play.api.db.DBApiProvider.get(DBModule.scala:62)
    at play.api.db.DBApiProvider.get(DBModule.scala:58)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
Caused by: play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error[Exception during pool initialization: HikariPool-0 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms.]
    at play.api.Configuration$.configError(Configuration.scala:154)
    at play.api.PlayConfig.reportError(Configuration.scala:996)
    at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool.create(HikariCPModule.scala:69)
    at play.api.db.PooledDatabase.createDataSource(Databases.scala:200)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.dataSource$lzycompute(Databases.scala:124)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.dataSource(Databases.scala:122)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.getConnection(Databases.scala:143)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.getConnection(Databases.scala:139)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi$$anonfun$connect$1.apply(DefaultDBApi.scala:44)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi$$anonfun$connect$1.apply(DefaultDBApi.scala:42)
Caused by: com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Exception during pool initialization: HikariPool-0 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms.
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.initializeConnections(HikariPool.java:526)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:136)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:71)
    at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool$$anonfun$1.apply(HikariCPModule.scala:58)
    at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool$$anonfun$1.apply(HikariCPModule.scala:54)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool.create(HikariCPModule.scala:54)
    at play.api.db.PooledDatabase.createDataSource(Databases.scala:200)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.dataSource$lzycompute(Databases.scala:124)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.dataSource(Databases.scala:122)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-0 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms.
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:195)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:147)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.initializeConnections(HikariPool.java:510)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:136)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:71)
    at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool$$anonfun$1.apply(HikariCPModule.scala:58)
    at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool$$anonfun$1.apply(HikariCPModule.scala:54)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool.create(HikariCPModule.scala:54)
    at play.api.db.PooledDatabase.createDataSource(Databases.scala:200)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Got minus one from a read call
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:489)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:553)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:254)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:528)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:95)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:101)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:314)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:171)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:436)
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Got minus one from a read call
    at oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:311)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:300)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1140)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:340)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:553)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:254)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:528)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:95)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:101)
```

And the browser shows:

```
Cannot connect to database [default]
```

I don't know what's going on. It seems to be that Play! is not recognizing the given connector but I just follow the wiki.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, using ojdbc6.jar and Oracle Db 11g, but with Play 2.7.x and after the "[warn] c.z.h.u.DriverDataSource - Registered driver with driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver was not found, trying direct instantiation" the application was still able to connect to database.

Anyway, I got rid of that warn by changing the OracleDriver class path (apparently it was wrong): in application.conf, I set "db.default.driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" instead of "db.default.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver". This should be enough to remove the warning, but I am not sure if this will solve the subsequent error in your specific case